# How can I implement this view in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have to implement a view in Android but have no idea how can I do it.

The view consists of 4 sublevels. I need to implement the last one but the others should be similar.

This should be the design:

[image]

A number 4 should be displayed in that circular button. What kind of button is that? Plus, how can I make that symbol ^ turn into upside down when clicked? Furthermore, how can I achieve that set of (logo-description-checkbox)?

As you can see I'm quite noob in Android but I've been 4 hours looking for information and have no idea where to start.

Comment: you can look into expandable list

Comment: I'd say go look at a few basic tutorials, learn how to lay simple layouts out and work from there, there are many resources available to you to help you learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kind of button is that?

You can use an ImageButton. Although it does not look like a button, but like a regular ImageView.

> how can I make that symbol ^ turn into upside down when clicked?

This is achieved with an [ExpandableList](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

> how can I achieve that set of (logo-description-checkbox)?

You can make a Horizontal LinearLayout with an ImageView, a TextView and a CheckBox with no text.